# Wordpress (avada theme) google fonts latin extended not working

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I've a problem with wordpress (using avada theme). I'm using Lato font (via google fonts) and some Turkish characters are not going well with Lato despide i choose latin extended (as you can see below). 
[image]

I've also added google fonts api manually and its still the same.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300italic,300,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You can check it out live by clicking http://v2w.bulutfon.com/bilgi-bankasi

Comment: I couldn't see the problem in my env.

* Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)
* OSX El Captain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lato font doesn't support those characters.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?query=lato

My advice, Google has developed a font which support all languages.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans?query=noto